# How do I make it so it only shows files with the .txt extension?

Tags: python, tkinter

Im using tkinter and I want to print out all the files in the folder that have a .txt extension.
This is the function im trying to do it in:

```
def view_notes():
    notes_program.destroy()

    global view_notes_screen
    view_notes_screen = Tk()
    view_notes_screen.title("View Notes")
    view_notes_screen.geometry("500x500")
    view_notes_screen.resizable(0, 0)

    global list_of_notes
    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            list_of_notes = os.path.join(file)
            print(list_of_notes)

    Label(view_notes_screen, text="Please use one of the filenames below:", bg="grey", width="500", height="2").pack()
    Label(view_notes_screen, text="").pack()
    Label(view_notes_screen, text=list_of_notes).pack()
```

I'm getting this error: (NameError: name 'list_of_notes' is not defined)
I'm confused on how to get this to work...

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the portion of code where `list_of_notes` is first defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for some code like this in your global scope
`list_of_notes=[]`

To make your code more readable you can get `list_of_notes` as func param instead of using global

You can also use glob for this task

```py
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(file)
```